# gcc undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'

Tags: c++

Write a boost test whether the installation was successful demo

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
int main(){
    int a = boost::lexical_cast<int>("123456");
    std::cout << a <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile error

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `std::cout'
test.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))'
/tmp/ccG8Wb2k.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccG8Wb2k.o: In function `std::exception::exception()':
```

Comment: you are most probably invoking `gcc` instead of `g++`, the difference is that the latter, by default, brings in the relevant c++ data upon invoking the *linker*. if you, for some unknown reason, want to use `gcc` use something like the following `gcc test.cpp -lstdc++`

Comment: Could you paste your compile command? Aren't you using gcc instead of g++ ?

Answer (score 8):

If you use `gcc` instead of `g++`, the C++ library is not automatically linked. This is from `man g++`:

> However, the use of gcc does not add the C++ library.  g++ is a
>   program that calls GCC and automatically specifies linking against the
>   C++ library.  It treats .c, .h and .i files as C++ source files
>   instead of C source files unless -x is used.  This program is also
>   useful when  precompiling a C header file with a .h extension for use
>   in C++ compilations.  On many systems, g++ is also installed with the
>   name c++.

As others have stated, either use `g++` directly or link `-lstdc++` at the end of your invocation. Something like `gcc main.cpp -lstdc++`.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles and runs no problem with g++ 4.8.1. Outputs:

```
123456
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:
g++ fileName.cpp -o Filename
That will output the file to be run.
I hope this will help you.
Regards
Martin Z