# Compiling NodeJS 4+ On CentOS 5

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm having an issue compiling NodeJS 4.2.3 (any version that requires c++ 4.8 and above) I've done the following:

- Compiled gcc4.8 (because gcc is 4.4 by default on CentOS 6
- Set the CXX option to point to the updated compiler
- Added the MPC, GMP and MPFR libraries via the LD_LIBRARY_PATH,

But I'm still getting the following error:

> gtest-test-part.cc:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN7testing14TestPartResult14ExtractSummaryEPKc+0xa):
>   undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
>   gtest-test-part.cc:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN7testing14TestPartResult14ExtractSummaryEPKc+0x1a):
>   undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' collect2: error:
>   ld returned 1 exit status

So, I see the following [gcc undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698059/gcc-undefined-reference-to-stdios-baseinitinit), but I'm not sure how to get that added, if it is at all possible, or if I'm supposed to add the library to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH? [I also saw this, but I don't have root (legacy systems not part of our cloud) so I can't apply all the advice given.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2773)

What is the correct way to get nodejs to compile with gcc4.8 compiled via source?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, I made this a lot more complicated than need be.

[The binaries are freely available for download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/stable/), and I suppose I could have compiled on another machine and then just downloaded them from there but I was unconsciously concerned about linking problems (or even problems referencing the kernel?), but it seems to be working fine. I usually think of getting binaries from RPMs that require root. This does not appear to have needed to be the case.